# Spark Streaming Context creation error

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Im trying Spark Streaming basic programming.,

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}

val appConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("kafkaapp");
val sContext = new StreamingContext(appConf , Seconds(1));
```

it returns the following

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
```

My Configuration

> Spark Core and Streaming "2.1.1" version Scala Version 2.11.8

What Im doing wrong?

POM File

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>streamapp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <inceptionYear>2008</inceptionYear>
  <properties>
    <scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>specs</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
          <args>
            <arg>-target:jvm-1.5</arg>
          </args>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if your runtime environment has the JAR with StreamingContext (should be spark-streaming_2.11.jar). If not, add missing dependency to your dependency management tool (Maven, SBT, Gradle...).

Comment: I have <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>

Comment: Could you add your pom.xml in the first question ? It'll help to understand  the issue better.

Comment: Thanks. Since you marked these dependencies as provided, Maven won't search them from remote repository. It expects you have them on your localhost. Thus, you can remove provided tag and retry.